# Can't Run The Include Files PhP Script Using Command Line?

Tags: php

I am having a php script that i would like to run on CLI (Command line Interface). I have used some echo statements in class a's constructor and from there I am calling its parrent constructor where i am using one more echo statement. i am not able to see the parent class's echo statement however If i run the same script with browser i can see all the echos. here is a part of my code.

```
class CImportEmployeeScript extends CScripts {
function __construct() {
    echo "Child File Constructor";
    parent::__construct();
}
    ----
    ----
}

class CScripts {
function __construct() {
    echo "In Parrent File";
    }
    ----
    ----
}
```

If my php files (Child And Parrent) do not use same path is their any possibility of the above problem..

Comment: So to sum up, you are instantiating a `CImportEmployeeScript` and you only see `Child File Constructor` output instead of `Child File ConstructorIn Parrent File` as you would expect from the above script? Do you get any error messages? Please can you `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of your script?

Comment: @DaveRandom I did that earlier.. but that doesn't help. It doesn't show any error.

Answer (score 1):

class **class CScripts** doesn't extend anything so remove **parent::__construct();**

Comment: A good point but I doubt this is the problem as you would still see the result of `echo "In Parrent File";` before you hit the inevitable fatal error.

Comment: @ARIF MAHMUD RANA thanks but that was just a writing mistake. i have corrected that.. Jazakallah-u-kher

Comment: @DaveRandom If the error reporting is stopped than how you will see the fatal error.